# Spring MVC repsonsebody

Tags: java, web-services, spring, rest, spring-mvc

Follwing the examples from [Krams](http://krams915.blogspot.co.uk/2011_02_26_archive.html). What does the below return, will the Person object be converted to JSON or XML based on the header of submitted request ?

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/person", 
           method = RequestMethod.POST, 
           headers="Accept=application/xml, application/json")
 public @ResponseBody Person addPerson(@RequestBody Person person) {
     logger.debug("Provider has received request to add new person");

     // Call service to here
     return personService.add(person);
    }
```

So when I submit data as json I get json back, and the same for xml. Or is something else going on ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on `Accept` http request header. If it's json, you get json, if it's xml you get xml.

That's exactly what this part of your code says.:

```
....
headers="Accept=application/xml, application/json")
...
```

You can send one mime type and receive another without problems.

**edit**

Both `headers` and `produces`/`consumes` parameters only say what **can** be produced/consumed by the requestmapping. They don't force any particular serialization. The type of request/response is decided entirely in request headers. If the dispatcher doesn't find mapping with `produces` and `consumes` (or headers) matching the request headers you'll get an error.

Comment: And using the produces and consumes parameters I could specify consuming XML and producing json (although maybe not the smartest idea) ?

Comment: @NimChimpsky yes, that's the idea.

Comment: @NimChimpsky `produces` and `consumes` are new parameters in spring mvc 3.1. They replace `headers` parameter when used for content type matching. So if you use spring 3.1 you should use `produces` and `consumes`.

Comment: I don't understand your edits.  Using "headers" parameter how could I receive one type and send another ? Or is this only possible with spring 3.1 and produces/consumes

Comment: in the code I posted if submit json data (the request header is json) I get json returned, how do I make it return xml if I submit json ?

Comment: @NimChimpsky you need to send a request with `Content-type: application/json` and `Accepts: application/xml`.

Answer (score 0):

The 'headers', 'produces', and 'consumes' parameters to @RequestMapping are one piece to the puzzle. They help the framework route incoming requests, and differentiate between requests based on values in the header.

The other part to this puzzle is the set of [MessageConverters](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/remoting.html#rest-message-conversion) that are configured in the application. The controller handler method in the example just returns an object, and the framework needs to know how to convert the object to some text representation (i.e. XML or JSON). MessageConverters are used on the inbound side (on parameters annotated with @RequestBody) and on the outbound side (when the method return value is annotated with @ResponseBody). The appropriate MessageConverter is chosen by the framework based on the media type of the incoming request.

When using the <mvc:annotation-driven> namespace in a Spring XML config file, or when using the @EnableMvc annotation on a Java Config class, MessageConverters supporting JSON and XML and configured automatically.